# How to print some free text in addition to SED extract

Tags: sed

Well-known SED command to extract a first line and print to another file

```
sed -n '1 p' /p/raw.txt | cat >> /p/001.txt ;
```

gives an output in /p/001.txt like

```
John Doe
```

But how to modify this command above to add some free text and have, for example, the output like

```
Name: John Doe
```

Thanks for any hint to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that in a single command (and no sub-shells):

```
sed 's/^/Name: /;q' /p/raw.txt >> /p/001.txt
```

This prefixes "Name: " in front of the first line, prints it, then quits so you don't process additional lines.  Add a line number before the `q` to print all lines up to (and including) that number.  The output is appended to `/p/001.txt` just like your original code.

If you want a range of lines:

```
sed -n '3,9{s/^/Name: /;p}9q' /p/raw.txt >> /p/001.txt
```

This reads from lines 3-9, performs the substitution, prints, then quits after line 9.

If you want specific lines, I recommend awk:

```
awk 'NR==3 || NR==9 { print "Name: " $0 } NR>=9 { exit }' /p/raw.txt >> /p/001.txt
```

This has two clauses.  One says the number of record (line number) is either 3 or 9, in which case we print the prefix and the line.  The other tells us to stop reading the file after the 9th record.

Here are two more commands to show how awk can act on just the first line(s) or a given range:

```
awk '{ print "Name: " $0 } NR >= 1 { exit }' /p/raw.txt >> /p/001.txt
awk '3 <= NR { print "Name: " $0 } NR >= 9 { exit }' /p/raw.txt >> /p/001.txt
```

---

It appears you're continuously building one file from the other. Consider:

```
tail -Fn0 /p/raw.txt |sed 's/^/Name: /' >> /p/001.txt
```

This will run continuously, adding only new entries (added after the command is run) to /p/001.txt

Perhaps you have lots of duplicates to resolve?

```
awk 'NR != FNR { $0 = "Name: " $0 } !s[$0]++' \
  /p/001.txt /p/raw.txt > /tmp/001.txt && mv /tmp/001.txt /p/001.txt
```

This folds together the previously saved names with any new names, printing names only once (`!s[$0]++` is true when `s[$0]` is zero (its default state), but after the evaluation, it increments to one, making it false on the second occurrence.  When a bare clause has no action, the line is printed.)  Because we're reading the output file, we need a temporary output. Upon its successful completion, we then move it atop the target output file.

Comment: sed only solution looks brilliant

Comment: **Very smart !** with all respect to sjsam first solution - this one is much more straight ! Adam, may be you could expand this to add not only **Name:** BEFORE but also something AFTER, for example **is unknown** ? To have a final output **Name: John Doe is unknown** ?

Comment: @Serge: Insert a 2nd `s` command that substitutes additional text for `$` (the end of the line): `sed 's/^/Name: /; s/$/ is unknown/; q'`

Comment: @sjsam Yes, perfect, TY for the hint. The only thing what worries me - this solution works for the first line only, as I understand. Am I right ? This case solution from sjsam is more expandable.

Comment: @Serge: The following example operates on line `2` only (while still exiting once the line of interest has been processed): `sed -n '2 { s/^/Name: /; s/$/ is unknown/; p; q; }' <<<$'line 1\nline 2\nline 3'`

Comment: Picking specific lines with GNU `sed`: `gsed -n -e '3ba' -e '9ba' -e 'b' -e ':a s/^/Prefix: /p' lines`  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
 printf "Name : %s\n" "$(sed -n '1p;q' /p/raw.txt)" >/p/001.txt
```

should do it. If `sed` is not a requirement do

```
echo -e "Name : $(sed -n '1p;q' /p/raw.txt)" >/p/001.txt
```

**Note**

1. The `q` option with the `sed` quits  it without processing any more commands or input.
2. The `-e` option tells echo to interpret escape sequences. This is a peculiarity of bash shell.

Comment: may be a syntax misprint somewhere ? because cli says `sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command`

Comment: @Serge: Corrected, You're right a `\n` creeped in `sed`

Comment: This variant `echo -e "Name : $(sed -n '1p;q' /p/raw.txt)" >/p/001.txt` is better for me, but interested to try variant from Adam too